# show/hide items in same time c# form

Tags: c#, windows

i have 20 picturebox in a C# form and rename this controls to p1,p2,p3
 now i should show/hide  this controls in same time.
now i need a idea  for change this controls perperty faster than it same array.
advance me for this

Comment: what do you want? can you be clearer?

Comment: one way to change property is p1.show();p2.hide();p3.show() and more but this code not god

Comment: do you ask how to change a property of an control on run-time? loop through the controls?

Comment: i have 2 picbox in from that this controls is a lite one off and another on now i need to show picbix1 to lite is on and hide picbox2 show to lite is off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood you write:

```
var PB = this.Controls.ofType<PictureBox>();
```

well return a `IEnumerable` of PictureBoxes's, containing all that are in the form.

```
foreach (var pb in PB)
  pb.Visible = false;
```

**edit** to check whether a pic-box is even or odd you could use the following:

```
String str = pb.name.subString(1);
if (Int32.parse(str) % 2 == 0)
    //even
else 
    //odd
```

Comment: this is good but i need to show odd picbox and hide even picbox in same time that this same flasher

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way is to add these 20 PictureBoxes to a `Panel` and then use its `Visible` property to *show/hide* them at the same time. The code could be this:

```
Panel container = new Panel();
//example, use whatever do you need
container = new Size(100, 100);
container = new Position(0, 0);
//add the panel to the form
this.Controls.Add(container);

//set the pictureboxes here...

//Add the pictureboxes to the panel
container.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]{p1, p2, p3}); //and so on

//Then when you need to show them
container.Visible = true; //false to hide them
```